# can't upgrade 1.9.3.0 to 1.9.3.10

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, magento-upgrade

I have tried through the Magento connect manager but it always ends with 
Nginx proxy 504

[image]

Also tried with

```
chmod +x mage
./mage mage-setup .
./mage config-set preferred_state stable
./mage sync
./mage install https://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```

but I get following output with some errors and seems to not upgrade to latest version

```
$ chmod +x mage
$ ./mage mage-setup .
Running initial setup...
Success
Success
Error: 
channel-add: Channel 'community' already exist!
$ ./mage mage-setup .
Running initial setup...
Success
Success
Successfully added: http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community
$ ./mage config-set preferred_state stable
Success
$ ./mage sync
Successfully added: community/Activo_CatalogSearch-1.1.0
Successfully added: community/Cm_RedisSession-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Interface_Adminhtml_Default-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Interface_Frontend_Base_Default-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Interface_Frontend_Default-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Interface_Frontend_Rwd_Default-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Interface_Install_Default-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Lib_Cm-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Lib_Credis-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Lib_Google_Checkout-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Lib_IDNA2-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Lib_Js_Calendar-1.51.1.6
Successfully added: community/Lib_Js_Ext-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Lib_Js_Mage-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Lib_Js_Prototype-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Lib_Js_TinyMCE-3.5.11.5
Successfully added: community/Lib_LinLibertineFont-2.8.14.6
Successfully added: community/Lib_Mage-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Lib_Magento-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Lib_Pelago-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Lib_Phpseclib-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Lib_Unserialize-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Lib_Varien-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Lib_ZF-1.12.10.5
Successfully added: community/Lib_ZF_Locale-1.12.10.5
Successfully added: community/Locale_Mage_community_it_IT-1.9.2.1.1
Successfully added: community/Mage_All_Latest-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Mage_Centinel-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Mage_Compiler-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Mage_Core_Adminhtml-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Mage_Core_Modules-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Mage_Downloader-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Mage_Locale_en_US-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Magento_Mobile-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Phoenix_Moneybookers-1.9.3.0
Successfully added: community/Sitewards_B2BProfessional-3.0.5
$ ./mage install https://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
PHP Warning:  scandir(/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/./errors): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Packager.php on line 243
PHP Warning:  scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Packager.php on line 243
Checking dependencies of packages
Error: 
install: Failed to delete files: /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/./pkginfo/Mage_All_Latest.txt 
 Check permissions
Error: 
install: Package community/Interface_Adminhtml_Default 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Interface_Adminhtml_Default 1.9.3.0
Package community/Interface_Adminhtml_Default 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Interface_Frontend_Default 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Interface_Frontend_Default 1.9.3.0
Package community/Interface_Frontend_Default 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Interface_Install_Default 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Interface_Install_Default 1.9.3.0
Package community/Interface_Install_Default 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Mage_Downloader 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Mage_Downloader 1.9.3.0
Package community/Mage_Downloader 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Mage_Centinel 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Mage_Centinel 1.9.3.0
Package community/Mage_Centinel 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Interface_Frontend_Base_Default 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Interface_Frontend_Base_Default 1.9.3.0
Package community/Interface_Frontend_Base_Default 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.9.3.0
Package community/Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Mage_Compiler 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Mage_Compiler 1.9.3.0
Package community/Mage_Compiler 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Magento_Mobile 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Magento_Mobile 1.9.3.0
Package community/Magento_Mobile 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Lib_Cm 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Lib_Cm 1.9.3.0
Package community/Lib_Cm 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Cm_RedisSession 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Cm_RedisSession 1.9.3.0
Package community/Cm_RedisSession 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Interface_Frontend_Rwd_Default 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Interface_Frontend_Rwd_Default 1.9.3.0
Package community/Interface_Frontend_Rwd_Default 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.9.3.0
Package community/Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.3.0
Package community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Lib_Js_Ext 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Lib_Js_Ext 1.9.3.0
Package community/Lib_Js_Ext 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Lib_LinLibertineFont 2.8.14.6: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Lib_LinLibertineFont 2.8.14.6
Package community/Lib_LinLibertineFont 2.8.14.6 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Lib_Js_TinyMCE 3.5.11.5: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Lib_Js_TinyMCE 3.5.11.5
Package community/Lib_Js_TinyMCE 3.5.11.5 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Lib_Varien 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Lib_Varien 1.9.3.0
Package community/Lib_Varien 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Lib_Google_Checkout 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Lib_Google_Checkout 1.9.3.0
Package community/Lib_Google_Checkout 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Lib_Js_Calendar 1.51.1.6: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Lib_Js_Calendar 1.51.1.6
Package community/Lib_Js_Calendar 1.51.1.6 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.3.0
Package community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Lib_Phpseclib 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Lib_Phpseclib 1.9.3.0
Package community/Lib_Phpseclib 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.9.3.0
Package community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Lib_Mage 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Lib_Mage 1.9.3.0
Package community/Lib_Mage 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Lib_Magento 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Lib_Magento 1.9.3.0
Package community/Lib_Magento 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Lib_Credis 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Lib_Credis 1.9.3.0
Package community/Lib_Credis 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Lib_Pelago 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Lib_Pelago 1.9.3.0
Package community/Lib_Pelago 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Lib_Unserialize 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Lib_Unserialize 1.9.3.0
Package community/Lib_Unserialize 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Lib_IDNA2 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Lib_IDNA2 1.9.3.0
Package community/Lib_IDNA2 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Lib_ZF 1.12.10.5: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Lib_ZF 1.12.10.5
Package community/Lib_ZF 1.12.10.5 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Lib_Js_Prototype 1.9.3.0: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Lib_Js_Prototype 1.9.3.0
Package community/Lib_Js_Prototype 1.9.3.0 installed successfully
Error: 
install: Package community/Lib_ZF_Locale 1.12.10.5: requires PHP version  >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0  current is: 7.1.22
Installing package community/Lib_ZF_Locale 1.12.10.5
Package community/Lib_ZF_Locale 1.12.10.5 installed successfully
Package installed: community/Interface_Adminhtml_Default 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Interface_Frontend_Default 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Interface_Install_Default 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Mage_Downloader 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Mage_Centinel 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Interface_Frontend_Base_Default 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Mage_Compiler 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Magento_Mobile 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Lib_Cm 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Cm_RedisSession 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Interface_Frontend_Rwd_Default 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Lib_Js_Ext 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Lib_LinLibertineFont 2.8.14.6
Package installed: community/Lib_Js_TinyMCE 3.5.11.5
Package installed: community/Lib_Varien 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Lib_Google_Checkout 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Lib_Js_Calendar 1.51.1.6
Package installed: community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Lib_Phpseclib 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Lib_Mage 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Lib_Magento 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Lib_Credis 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Lib_Pelago 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Lib_Unserialize 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Lib_IDNA2 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Lib_ZF 1.12.10.5
Package installed: community/Lib_Js_Prototype 1.9.3.0
Package installed: community/Lib_ZF_Locale 1.12.10.5
```

NOTE the site has been working and has updated succesfully from 1.8.x upwards a few times and all this time php 7 was running

I have setup so that php 5.6 the default php used with alias

```
alias php='/usr/bin/php5.6'
```

and made sure `php -v` gives php 5.6 but to no avail

Answer (score 1):

Well, at least through Magento Connect you should choose either update Mage_All_Latest, which contains the full update, or choose below what to update individually. 
From your screenshot I see you choose both Mage_All_Latest and the individual options. This leads to a lot of compatibility errors that take a long time to appear....maybe this causes your error?

Answer (score 0):

What i did to install this update through Magento Connect

I changed the php version to 5.6 and after updating "Mage_All_Latest" i changed php back to 7.1.
That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Download magento 1.9.3.10
And unpack zip.
Copy all files to your magento folder with replacing old files , but then you will replacing them , check for safe (check updates) 
.

Comment: Not sure where to find direct downloads for magento.

Comment: https://magento.com/tech-resources/download   search on page in the down version 1.9.3.10, login, press download in zip or another compressed file format. Unpack and try my solution.

Comment: http://rgho.st/download/7C6FDQvQc/0791f3f50775897989a0efe2df26ddeffb2c8bb6/0791f3f50775897989a0efe2df26ddeffb2c8bb6/magento-1.9.3.10-2018-09-18-03-18-14.zip

Comment: Or try this one - http://rgho.st/7C6FDQvQc

Comment: I uploaded it for you on filehosting.

Comment: If youll some troubles , write to me , i will help you..

Comment: Don't see any download for 1.9.3.10 on that page @alexey boltynov

Comment: Check next link pls